# Prove that if a real vector space V has more than one vector then it has infinitely many vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

I cannot seem to come up with a proof for this one. It makes sense to me in my head but i cannot seem to make a logical step by step process for a proof that show this is true.

Comment: Hint: if there are at least two distinct vectors, then one of them must be $\ne \vec 0$.

Comment: If a vector space has more than one vector, then one of them is not the zero vector (which is unique), call it $v_0$. How many vectors $\alpha v_0$ are there?

Answer (score 2):

A real vector space with one vector would just be the space containing the zero vector. So if it has more than one vector, it must have at least one non-zero vector $\vec{v}$. Then, since it's a real vector space, it's closed under scalar multiplication with reals, so for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$, $c\vec{v}$ is also in the space.

So there are an infinite number of ways to construct vectors in the space, so all you have to do is confirm that they're distinct, and you can use some of the other behaviours of vectors to do that (basically, prove that if they weren't distinct, that they would have to all equal the zero vector).